# sendemail.php not sending an email when I click send email

Tags: php, html, forms

When I run it locally it gives me an error of

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

or an error of

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

when run on my domain.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the send email code (___ in place of my personal email):

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
       'message'=>'Your email has been sent!'
    );
    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $phone = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = '____@gmail.com';
    
    
    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
    ?>
```

here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="padding-ten-lr padding-100px-tb padding-70px-tb sm-padding-50px-tb sm-no-padding-lr">
                        <div class="">
                            <span class="alt-font theme-color margin-5px-bottom  text-center letter-spacing-1 display-block">Contact</span>
                            <h4 class="font-weight-300 font-size32 md-font-size27 sm-font-size24 xs-font-size20 margin-10px-bottom text-center">Get In Touch</h4>
                            <div class="margin-70px-bottom sm-margin-40px-bottom xs-margin-30px-bottom separator-line-horizontal-medium-light2 bg-theme center-col"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="no-margin-lr" id="success-contact-form"></div>
                        <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="contact-form" action="sendemail.php">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="medium-input" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name *" required="required" id="name" name="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="medium-input" maxlength="70" placeholder="E-mail *" required="required" id="email" name="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="tel" class="medium-input" maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" name="phone">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="medium-input" maxlength="78" placeholder="Subject *" required="required" id="subject" name="subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea class="big-textarea" rows="6" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Message *" required="required" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

any help appreciated. thank you

I have tried to unsuppress the mail() function by removing @ but that did not help

Comment: First of all, stop suppressing errors with `@` across the board, especially if you're debugging. Proper error reporting exists for good reason. Also, if you're getting warnings due to `$_POST` variables not set, do the proper checks, instead of suppressing your `@trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']))` etc. Further, set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get more detailed information on what's going on. That will likely give you sufficient information to solve this without even asking here.

Comment: 405 sounds like your webserver doesn't support postbacks- and I would guess from that it doesn't support  php either. So probably you need to ensure you run this code on a platform which is actually capable of doing so. What are you using currently as a server?